# AWS Mastodon EC2 Instance intermittently timeouts

Tags: amazon-ec2, mastodon

I set up a Mastodon AWS instance. It connects fine, but will give my browser a "time out" message on very simple tasks, but only periodically.

I don't know how to begin to track down the problem. Are there SSH commands I can run inside the instance to see what's actually happening?

Thanks.

I tried the journalctl log output command for some of the services, but there was nothing.

Also looked at the developer's output on the Chrome browser, but nothing.